# ORACLE - replace text in a clob with data held in a table on a large amount of data

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

So I have a table table1 and it has a column col_clob which is a clob. I also have a table2 that has 2 columns col_old_value and col_new_value. table1 has millions of rows, table2 has hundreds of thousands of rows.
I want to:

```
update t1 set t1.col_clob = replace(t1.col_clob,t2.col_old_value , t2.col_new_value)
from table1 t1, table2 t2
where instr(t1.col_clob, t2.col_old_value,1,1)>0
```

This obviously takes forever and may never finish so I'm looking better ways to do it please.
Have been trying all sorts but none are working

Comment: reduce the amount try 100009 at a time, see how long it takes and then write a python script

Comment: Have you considered whether you can do this as a new table instead? https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:6407993912330 says "you can do that using parallel query, with nologging on most operations generating very little redo and no undo at all -- in a fraction of the time it would take to update the data". Even if that doesn't make sense in your case, it seems plausible a clob->clob function that does all the t2 replacements would be better since you would only rewrite each t1 row once.

Comment: How many old/new replacement pairs per single CLOB? One? Or many?

Comment: Btw, Oracle has no such syntax `UPDATE..FROM..WHERE..` unfortunately, anyway I also suggest using `CREATE TABLE ... AS` ...

Comment: For performing updates on large amounts of data, you may use the facilities of dbms_parallel_execute. For instance, see: https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/dbms_parallel_execute_11gR2

Comment: You are using a `PostgreSQL` syntax to update an `Oracle` DB. Your approach is *non-deterministic*, e.g. if you update old value `AA` to new value `BB` and `AAA` to `CCC` then the result depends on the *order* in which you replace. Your join will provide potentially *hundreds of billions* of rows! This does not seem to be ideal job for a RDBMS. I’d suggest some in memory text processing that works linear for the number of replaces. Voting to close – please feel free to update the question based on the points above.